# Pretty permalinks don't work with GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, permalinks, github-pages

Pretty permalinks are working file locally but not once deployed to GitHub Pages. Puzzled what might be a reason. Pages can be still accessed via `.html`.

_config.yml

```
title: Project Name
baseurl: /project-name
url: "http://organization-name.github.io"
google_analytics: # set tracking

gems:
  - jekyll-redirect-from

exclude:
 - Gemfile
 - Gemfile.lock

permalinks: pretty
markdown: kramdown
```

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

group :jekyll_plugins do
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax is `permalink: pretty` : singular.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this issue by adding permalink explicitly to page meta. E.g.

```
permalink: /about/
```

Strange that it is not required locally.

Comment: Your local Jekyll install uses a different web server to GitHub Pages with a different-but-similar routing configuration, which would explain the difference handling the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your _config.yml

```
defaults:
-
   scope:
     path: ""
     type: "pages"
   values:
     permalink: "/:basename/"
```

You may want to tweak this example.

For example, if you want to keep your folder structure in your permalinks, you could have:

```
defaults:
-
   scope:
     path: ""
     type: "pages"
   values:
     permalink: "/:path/:basename/"
```

Note: **"pretty"** is **"/:path/:basename/"**